# Stay on current page after POST data

Tags: php, forms

i have form which genrate from a specific search button.the newly generated form has several form wich can update it's own data
how to doing such a  update without any affect to current page.
because of search result and search parameter should not be change.
eventually question in sort, give me an idea to "update each record based on query search while displaying it'.

ex:

```
<pre>
**name:[** k%  **]  branch:[** acc  **]  SEARCH**  >>>>search form

EMPID  |  NAME   |  BRANCH | EDIT |   
 1     |  kamal  |  acc    | edit |  >>>>>>dynamicaly generated form based query serch 
 2     |  kapila |  acc    | edit |  >>>>>>dynamicaly generated form based query serch 

</pre>
```

thank you..
here my try

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../../config/config.inc.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../../css/tbl.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/formControll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function autoSubmit(){

  document.forms['searchForm'].action=SCRIPT_NAME;
  document.forms['searchForm'].submit();
  alert("done");
  return true;
 }
 </script>
<title>OT Detail</title>

</head>

<body>
 <?php  
   $errors = array();
   $htmlcode="";
   $me = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
if(isset($_GET["invalid"])) //that means this is a redirected session
{   
//form data default value initialization goes here
$Year=$_GET["Year"];
$Month=$_GET["Month"];

      echo "<br><br><strong>ERROR: ";
      foreach($_GET["errors"] as $k=>$v)
        echo "<font color=red >".$v."</font>";
     echo "</strong>";                      
}
else//if $_GET["invalid"] is not define then this is not redirecting session
{ 
//form data default value initialization goes here
$Year=date("Y");
$Month=date("m");

}                         

//for sequrity reasons we check weather 'REQUEST_METHOD'== 'POST'                     

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){


   //server side manual form validation goes here
   if (!$_POST['Year'])
      $errors[0] = "Year ?";

   if (!$_POST['Month'])
      $errors[1] = "Month?";

      if (count($errors)>0){
      header("Location:setOtPermit.php?invalid=1&Year=".$_POST["Year"]."&Month=".$_POST["Month"]."&errors=".$errors);
      exit;
      } 
      else //no error
      {

        //get post array 
     foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if ($key!="Search"){
      $value=htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags($value)));
      ${$key}=$value;

      }//if $key
      }//4e 


     //******* building sql for search 
$sql="SELECT branch FROM ".$tbl_name2." WHERE empNo=".$_SESSION['resideFigure'];
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con)or die("cannot query");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM);
$myBranch="Finance";//$row[0];
//echo $myBranch;

$sql="select * from ".$tbl_name4." e  
where e.empNo in( 
select d.empNo
from ".$tbl_name2." d
where d.branch='".$myBranch."') and e.empNo=000123 and e.permitMonth=1";
//echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con)or die("cannot query");

//*** search result feching into table goes here
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
    $htmlcode.="<center><table id='myDisplay'>";


    $htmlcode.="<tr>";
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $htmlcode.="<th>".mysql_field_name($result,$i)."</th>";
    }//for mysql_num_fields
    $htmlcode.="</tr>";


    $rowAlter=true;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $htmlcode.="<form name='myform[]' method='POST' action='".$me."' onSubmit='return validateForm()'>";
     if($rowAlter)
     {$htmlcode.="<tr>";
     $rowAlter=false;
     }
     else
     {
     $htmlcode.="<tr class='alt'>";
     $rowAlter=true;
     }
     foreach($row as $k=>$v)
     {
     $htmlcode.="<td><input type='text' name='mydata[]' value='".$v."'></td>";
     }//4e
     $htmlcode.="<td><input type='submit' name='Update'  onclick='autoSubmit()' value='Update'></td></tr>";
    }//while
    $htmlcode.="</form></table></center>";
    }
    else//when data not fetched
    {
     echo "<br><br><font color=blue >It seems to be you have not done any OT Permission!</font>";
    }





     }//else error count 
    }//if $_SERVER

?>   

<center><form name="searchForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo strip_tags($me);?>" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
         <tr>
            <td>Year</td><td><input type="text" name="Year" value="<?php echo $Year;?>"></td>
            <td>Month</td><td><input type="text" name="Month" value="<?php echo $Month;?>"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
 </form></center>
 <script type="text/javascript">SetHandlers()</script>

<?php
//display result as table
if (count($errors)==0)
echo $htmlcode;

//for sequrity reasons & confirm to dynamic form are submited we check weather 'REQUEST_METHOD'== 'POST'                        
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['Update'])){} 
echo "if success i can do this its not difficult,but things is result desapper";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: I see several $_GET values, but the form is submitting using post.  So unless you are adding the $_GET variables to the url elsewhere, $_GET['year'] (for example) would be empty.  Do you understand the difference between $_GET and $_POST?

Answer (score 1):

I like to post the information back to the same page.  You can use php to handle the post at the start of the script and then you already have all the data you submitted so you can populate the search field and everything using that data.

Alternatively don't submit the form but perform an ajax query.  That way your current page remains unchanged.

Comment: you mean if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){//query result here}//form is here

Comment: Yes, there are other ways as well... if(isset(#_POST['submit'])){}.  Or any other variable that is set.

Comment: when i search once it will disappear what key word had enter to search
therefore i used $_get array also.but how to update specific result without affecting so there two php handler to catch _self post

Comment: I don't get what you mean.  Do you mean you have 2 forms?  They can both post back and you can have two handlers by setting the name of the submit button to unique values: <input type="submit" name="submitFrm1"/>.  Then you have `if(isset($_POST['submitFrm1'])){}else if(isset($_POST['submitFrm2']){}`

Comment: my code is given if it is difficult to understand my code give another idea to like "ms accsess tabular form" which we can do search ,view update staying in a single page.